# Adicionar campos de formulario com jQuery para ser enviado em php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Estou usando o seguinte código para adicionar um novo grupo de campos a um formulário que será enviado por e-mail em php

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("a[id='addProd']").click(function() {
          var domElement = $('<div class="block product" id="novoProduto"><p><label for="tituloProd1">Título do Produto: </label><input type="text" name="tituloBanner1" placeholder="Título do Banner: "><label for="descricaoProd1">Descrição do Produto: </label><textarea name="descricaoProd1" placeholder="Descrição do Banner: "></textarea><label for="fotoProd1">Foto do Produto</label><input type="file" class="typeFile" name="fotoProd1"></p></div>');
          $(this).before(domElement);
      });
  });
```

```css
form label {
 font-size: 1.4em;
 margin: 20px 0 10px;
 display: block;
}
form input {
 width: 97%;
 height: 35px;
 padding-left: 2%;
 background: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
form .typeFile {
 width: 97%;
 height: 35px;
 padding-left: 0;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
form textarea {
 width: 97%;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 2% 0 0 2%;
 background: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="block product">
       <p><label for="tituloProd1">Título do Produto/Serviço: </label>
       <input type="text" name="tituloBanner1" placeholder="Título do Banner: ">

       <label for="descricaoProd1">Descrição do Produto/Serviço: </label>
       <textarea name="descricaoProd1" placeholder="Descrição do Banner: "></textarea>

       <label for="fotoProd1">Foto do Produto/Serviço</label>
       <input type="file" class="typeFile" name="fotoProd1"></p>
      </div>
      <a href="#novoProduto" id="addProd"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Adicionar Produto</a></button>
</form>
```

Está funcionado, porém desta forma todos os novos campos irão ser inseridos com o mesmo *name=""* e creio que vá dar algum tipo de erro na hora de enviar o formulario.

Creio que com algum *for* no jQuery eu consiga resolver isso, tentei isso, porém não funcionou. Alguém pode me ajudar com uma solução? Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como sugerido acima, para receber esse formulário facilmente, basta você colocar os atributos 'name' como array.

Seguindo sua lógica de enumerar os blocos, segue um exemplo simples.

OBS: Não duplique o ID de um elemento.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[id='addProd']").click(function() {
    var index = $('.block.product').length + 1;
    var domElement = $('<div class="block product"><p><label for="tituloProd' + index + '">Título do Produto: </label><input type="text" name="tituloBanner' + index + '" placeholder="Título do Banner: "><label for="descricaoProd' + index + '">Descrição do Produto: </label><textarea name="descricaoProd' + index + '" placeholder="Descrição do Banner: "></textarea><label for="fotoProd' + index + '">Foto do Produto</label><input type="file" class="typeFile" name="fotoProd' + index + '"></p></div>');
    $(this).before(domElement);
  });
});
```

```css
form label {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  display: block;
}
form input {
  width: 97%;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
form .typeFile {
  width: 97%;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
form textarea {
  width: 97%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2% 0 0 2%;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="block product">
    <p>
      <label for="tituloProd1">Título do Produto/Serviço:</label>
      <input type="text" name="tituloBanner1" placeholder="Título do Banner: ">

      <label for="descricaoProd1">Descrição do Produto/Serviço:</label>
      <textarea name="descricaoProd1" placeholder="Descrição do Banner: "></textarea>

      <label for="fotoProd1">Foto do Produto/Serviço</label>
      <input type="file" class="typeFile" name="fotoProd1">
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#novoProduto" id="addProd"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Adicionar Produto</a>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse cado você vai ter que transformar seus inputs em array.
Basta adicionar `[]` depois do `name` assim:

```
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
```

Com isso você vai poder armazenar mais de um valor.
Espero ter ajudado.

Veja mais aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays